# ajax response not recieving

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, ajax

Will anyone help me in this regard. My problem is that when I ajax request WordPress, when I log that response in console it shows `error/complete` not `response`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".pincode_search_field").on('keyup', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var ajax_url = pin_shop.ajax_url;
    var pincode_search_field = $(this).val();
    var nonce  = $(this).data('nonce');

    $.ajax({
        url: ajax_url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'action'        : 'pincode_search_field',
            'nonce'         : nonce,
            'search_query'  : pincode_search_field,
        },
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        console.log(response.database_result);
        console.log('success');
    })
    .fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
});
```

});

Here is my PHP code.

```
  add_action( "wp_ajax_pincode_search_field", 'pincode_search_field' );
add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_pincode_search_field", 'pincode_search_field' );

function pincode_search_field() {
    global $wpdb;
    $pincode = $_REQUEST['search_query'];
    if ( wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['nonce'], "pin_shop_nonce") ) {
        $result['database_result'] = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT shop_id FROM cs_shop_details WHERE shop_pincode = $pincode");
        $result = json_encode( $result );
        echo $result;
        die();
    }
}
```

Here is the enqueue script.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'pin-js', plugins_url() . '/pin-shop/inc/pin.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_localize_script( 'pin-js', 'pin_shop', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), 
    ) );
});
```

EDIT: Here is the result in console log.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per jQuery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), `dataType: 'json'` is supported.  That is the thing that is being **returned** and parsed by jQuery to your success function.  There is more information needed to resolve your issue.

<strike>Does `pin_shop.ajax_url` properly resolve to `//site.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`?  If not, there's your first problem.  (To check this, `console.log(ajax_url);` just before your $.ajax call.</strike>  I see your enqueue has this.

(Also, did you notice you're not returning your result to the AJAX caller?  I put a note of it in the code below.)

<strike>Next, you might not be sending your nonce.  Check that `$(this).data('nonce')` resolves to the nonce?  (To check this, `console.log(nonce);` just before your $.ajax call.)</strike>

Finally, you may not be resolving your nonce correctly on the server side.  To primitively check this, comment out a few lines in your PHP code and see if *success/complete* is logged to the console, like so:

```
function pincode_search_field() {
    global $wpdb;
//  if ( wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['nonce'], "pin_shop_nonce") ) {
        $result['database_result'] = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM cs_shop_details WHERE pincode = '192124'");
        $result = json_encode( $result );
        die();
//  }
}
```

Lastly, there might be an error in your SQL (as in the table`cs_shop_details` does not exist or the `pincode` field does not exist in that table).  To check that, comment out `$result['database_result'] = ...` and set `$result=array()` so that an empty result will be returned (and make sure `$result` is echoed).

(Also, I'm new so if any of this helps, and upvote would be appreciated to help me get my score up so that I can comment.)

**EDIT:**  A little debugging, and the problem was learned to be that the PHP function is not echo-ing the json encoded result:  add `echo $result;` just before `die()`.

**EDIT 2:**  In helping to debug the JSON response.  First, note the `$wpdb->get_results()` will return an array.  You put that array into the *database_result* index of the *$results* array.  So, your structure now looks like this...

```
Array (
    'database_result' => Array (
        [0] => Array(
            "shop_id" => 1
        )
        ... (other results here, indexed sequentially)
    )
)
```

So, this array is what is being returned to `.done()`.  Access this array accordingly via the `response` JSON object passed to the related function.  I think something like `response.database_result[0]["shop_id"]` or `response.database_result[0].shop_id`.

Comment: everything works fine, just showing undefined when i use response.database_result in console

Comment: here is the status of code
Request URL: http://localhost/cs/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: You say "response in console it shows error/complete not response" ... that means the `.fail()` and `.always()` blocks of your AJAX are executing.  In order for the `.done()` to execute, the AJAX call must be a success, failing which response.database_result will always be null.  What is the value of ajax_url and nonce when logged in the manner I suggested?

Comment: that problem is solved by removing datatype.

Comment: this is nonce = 4e499f192b. everything works fine. now when i use response.databas_result in frontend it shows undefined, even everything works fine

Comment: let me update code

Comment: I see. With dataType put back in, all should be well if you have `echo $result;` command in your PHP code (in the place I provide in my example above).

Comment: everything works fine now. one more confusion. here is the response i am getting
0:
shop_id: "1"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
in console.
i want to show id that is 1. how to do that. any sugestion

Comment: also datatype has no effect if i set it.

Comment: If you echo a json encoded object, AJAX will "guess" that you intended to put `dataType: json` in your AJAX call.  Best practice is to define the dataType (so there is no guessing).  Need a bit more info on the response output.  What is the javascript you're using?  Is it still `console.log(response.database_result);`?

Comment: yes, it is it, you mentioned

Comment: I would just play around a bit.  Try changing to `console.log(response.database_result.shop_id);` or `console.log(response.database_result["shop_id"]);`

Comment: it shows undefined in console

Comment: But `console.log(response.database_result);` shows `shop_id: "1" proto: Object length: 1`?  And you have `$result['database_result'] = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT shop_id FROM cs_shop_details WHERE shop_pincode = $pincode");` still the same in your PHP code?  One more question:  is shop_pincode unique to each record in cs_shop_details, or can more than one record have the same shop_pincode?

Comment: no many shops will have same pincode if they are in same location. so i am filtering results with pincode. once user fills the pincode he will get the list of shops with that pincode.

Comment: OK.  Let me edit my answer so I can respond properly.  (I see your screenshot, thank you.  I think I need more characters than what is allowed in the comments.)

Comment: added screenshot in question please check

Comment: Answer updated in regards to handling of your `$result` by AJAX `.done()`.

Comment: thank you very much works like a charm. again thanks for help

Comment: You betcha.  I would encourage you to put back the `dataType: 'json',` in your AJAX call just to make sure that AJAX doesn't sporadically decide to "guess" that you're returning something other than a JSON while you have your back turned.